# How do I open .exe in ubuntu without wine or any other windows compatibility layer?

Tags: windows, wine

I tried to open some .exe files with wine, like Minecraft team extreme. It ran, but it was lagging too much! How do I run an .exe file without Windows/DOS/Wine?

Comment: If wine doesn't work for you, then you are out of luck. Minecraft itself will run on Linux without wine. What does "minecraft team extrem" do?

Comment: @MadMike It's a pirated ver. of Minecraft.

Answer (score 14):

Windows and Linux are built on very different backends, and run very different types of programs.

While there are equivalencies like `.so` objects and `.dll` files, `.exe` files are not the same as a shell file.

You could, under very controlled conditions with a highly customized OS named Windows with a Linux theme, run a `.exe` file. You will not be able to run Linux executables, however, without installing a compatibility layer like WSL and/or Cygwin. Note, though, that you'll still need an X server and a whole bunch of other things to make everything work right.

There are ways to run `exe` files on plain Linux, though:

1. Take a Bash shell script named `test`. Rename it to `test.exe`. You are running an EXE!!
2. Install Wine. As you mentioned, this is pretty laggy. You might be able to get around that by ***not playing games***. You could try to tweak it for performance by changing the Wine settings, but you can only tweak it so much.
3. [Install PlayOnLinux](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PlayOnLinux#How_to_install_PlayOnLinux). It is a specially designed version of Wine that reduces lag in a few ways. First off, each program has it's own instance of Wine. This  slightly speeds up the PC. Also, PlayOnLinux will automatically optimize Wine (including choosing the right version!!) to make your game as good as possible.
4. Run a VM. You can use VirtualBox (free) to run a licensed and registered copy of Windows. This can cause all sorts of problems though, as *it'll be slower than Wine*.
5. Just Dual-Boot.  This will give you the most performance, but you still need a licensed copy of Windows. It also requires you to reboot into Windows.

There are no real good ways to run Windows programs in Linux, but it is possible.

Comment: "You will not be able to run Linux executables without a VM or Cygwin, though." Scratch that. Now you can.

Comment: --^ you should update this KazWolfe

Answer (score 9):

**.exe** will not work on Ubuntu if you do not have Wine installed, there is no way around this as you are trying to install a Windows program into a Linux operating system.

I refer you to this site for further information.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine

Comment: I do have wine installed, but I ran a .exe file without thinking too much, it worked no problems and it was only later I had run the windows version of the application (a linux file was also provided), I'm just curious how this happened behind the scenes? I know Windows and Linux have very different back ends, Linux version of .exe are ELF files, so I am confused what happened here. Was wine invoked automatically because I have it on my system?

It was just a CLI program so no windows or anything, but it worked with no issue....

Answer (score 2):

Linux does not understand **.exe** files this is a Microsoft format so It's not possible without some additional compatibility layer.

Options for this are [Wine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine), [PlayOnLinux](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PlayOnLinux) neither of which is perfect.

The other option is to run Windows which you can either do by dual booting or installing visualisation software such as [Virtualbox](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox) or [VMware](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware) but these need a Windows licence and valid install media.

Comment: wine isn't the best you see, but dual boot!!! ;-( I tried 2b (dual boot) when I had on dual boot edubuntu and PLEASE don't mention it AGAIN! It were stucking so much that I wanted to KILL myself! It's because I haven't a stong processor enough to do the work (Intel atom inside) I thing play on linux is the best choice! (might...)